# center div in container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal, centering

Using bootstrap I am trying to center the div with the class `smframe`. I have tried various different CSS styles and have been struggling the last few hours. What also seems to be happening is the paragraph text is showing under the image in the div with the class of `smframe` instead of below it.

```css
.armando {
    background-image: url("../images/armando.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: scale-down;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    padding-top: 20px;

}
 .three {
    height: 30rem;
    width: auto;
    border: 2px solid white;
  }
  
  .smframe {

width: 20rem;
height: 16rem;
margin: auto;
border: 3px solid white;
margin-top: 2rem;
box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

.frame1 {

  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid #8d9ba0;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

```html
<div class=" container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="container darkBG three col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><h4 class="text-center">Sleeping arrangements</h4>
          <div class="smframe bedroom"></div>
          <div class=""><p>Sleeps 2/4 + baby (1 Bedroom)The bedroom double Bed and the lounge has a double couch bed and a baby cot.</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container darkerBG three col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><h4 class="text-center">Albufeira Old Town</h4>
          <div class="smframe rooftop"></div>
          <div class=""><p>Sleeps 2/4 + baby (1 Bedroom)The bedroom double Bed and the lounge has a double couch bed and a baby cot.</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container darkestBG three col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><h4 class="text-center">Local bars and resturants</h4>
          <div class="smframe armando"></div>
          <div class=""><p>Sleeps 2/4 + baby (1 Bedroom)The bedroom double Bed and the lounge has a double couch bed and a baby cot.</p></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Centering**

Hmm, using your code, your image is already centered. The key is the `margin: auto` that does the centering for you. If you don't want to use that, as an alternative centering method, you could try using `flexbox`.

**Positioning**

As far as the text not showing below your image, this is because you applied `position: absolute`. Remove that and it should render as expected.

```css
.armando {
  background-image: url("https://imgc.allpostersimages.com/img/posters/leo-cullum-scotch-and-toilet-water-new-yorker-cartoon_u-L-PGQ1WD0.jpg?src=gp&w=300&h=375");
}

.bedroom {
  background-image: url("https://pre00.deviantart.net/5580/th/pre/f/2012/355/f/8/comic__sleeping_reality_by_ayuma__chan-d5or92n.png");
}

.rooftop {
  background-image: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/lowres.cartoonstock.com/restaurants-chinese_restaurant-chinese_cuisine-chinese_food-danger_zones-danger_signs-hscn751_low.jpg");
}

.three {
  height: 30rem;
  width: auto;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.smframe {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  margin: auto; //if you remove this, it will no longer be centered
  border: 3px solid white;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  // position: absolute; --> remove this
  object-fit: scale-down;
  // transform: rotate(90deg);
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.frame1 {
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid #8d9ba0;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

```html
<div class=" container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container darkBG three col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <h4 class="text-center">Sleeping arrangements</h4>
      <div class="smframe bedroom"></div>
      <div class="">
        <p>Sleeps 2/4 + baby (1 Bedroom)The bedroom double Bed and the lounge has a double couch bed and a baby cot.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container darkerBG three col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <h4 class="text-center">Albufeira Old Town</h4>
      <div class="smframe rooftop"></div>
      <div class="">
        <p>Sleeps 2/4 + baby (1 Bedroom)The bedroom double Bed and the lounge has a double couch bed and a baby cot.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container darkestBG three col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <h4 class="text-center">Local bars and resturants</h4>
      <div class="smframe armando"></div>
      <div class="">
        <p>Sleeps 2/4 + baby (1 Bedroom)The bedroom double Bed and the lounge has a double couch bed and a baby cot.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you removing position absoloute worked and for strangly everything looks centered now, thanks a lot, much appriciated

Answer (score -2):

Try add this styles to `smframe`:

```
<div class="smframe" style="width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></div>
```

Comment: if the width is 100% then how it will get centered?

Comment: Because of that margin.